# asymptotic normality of Generalized Least Square

Tags: econometrics, asymptotics, law-of-large-numbers

I am kind of new to this matrix notation and properties so I would like to see the algebraic part of the solution it helps to understand so I appreciate your understanding.

My question is basically:

here from $y=X\beta+u$

we have that expression from GLS estimation and Central Limit Theorem.

$ \sqrt{n}\cdot(\hat{\beta} -\beta) = \left(\dfrac{(X^T \Omega^{-1}X)}{n} \right)^{-1} \cdot \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}} X^T \Omega^{-1} u$

We have that:

$\sqrt{n}\cdot(\hat{\beta} -\beta)  \xrightarrow[]{d} N\left(0,\sigma^2 \left(\dfrac{(X^T \Omega^{-1}X)}{n} \right)^{-1}\right) $

do we have to assume $\lim$ of $ \left(\dfrac{(X^T \Omega^{-1}X)}{n} \right)^{-1}$ should be equal to some Positive definite, finite matrix like $Q$ as in the case of OLS like $\left(\dfrac{(X^T X)}{n} \right)^{-1} $
and how we can really reach that result ?
or is there something different I should learn ? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this [note](http://www2.econ.osaka-u.ac.jp/~tanizaki/class/2019/econome2/TA_session01.pdf).

Comment: Yes, we have to assume that it is finite and nonsingular (if it's nonsingular, it's positive definite by construction.)  What is your concern - that you don't understand how you get to the limiting distribution of $\sqrt{n}\cdot (\hat{\beta}-\beta)$, or...

Comment: Yes, I was just confused about how to deal with the Omega term but the notes above are smooth and useful. thanks, both of you.